# Dismiss 2 modal view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have a base modal view controller. i then create a 2nd one with:

```
FieldReportViewController *fieldReport = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fieldReportView"];
[self presentModalViewController:fieldReport animated:YES];
```

from there, i call a 3rd view controller with:

```
ScoutingReportViewController *scoutingReport = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ScoutView"];
[self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:scoutingReport animated:YES];
```

now i want to return back to the first view controller. i've tried (this is currently shown view controller):

```
-(IBAction)doneBtn
{
    //[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  //removed

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];    //added

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CloseAllModalViews" object:nil userInfo:nil];  //added

}
```

in middle/s view controller, i add an observer in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(dismissModals:)
                                             name:@"CloseAllModalViews"
                                           object:nil];
```

and method:

```
-(void) dismissModals:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

when pressed, it does nothing. it does not dismiss any views.

any ideas how i can get this to work?

EDIT: figured out why it was crashing; i had forgotten i added a segue to my done button in IB. this lead to memory issues and was causing the crash.

EDIT 2: this will dismiss both view controllers back to the base/first view controller. it does not give me any animations though. i can dismiss current VC with no animate and dismiss middle VC with animation, but i see the middle VC briefly before the transition. i'd prefer to to have an animation from the current VC to the base VC if possible.

Comment: No hints on the console when you run it on the device? Any warnings from xcode when you build it?

Comment: nope, no crash info in the console when i run it on the ipad. i've noticed that xcode 4.2 gives a lot less feed back then previous versions on crashes.  =/

Comment: If your first viewcontroller was a navigationcontroller, you could use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`. Like to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before, and I had to use UINotificationCenter to dismiss the middle views. When you press your doneBtn, post a notification. Before you push your other views, add an observer with your dismissModal as the action. If you remove the animation, it should look like you just went back to the original view.

In your view you want to auto dismiss:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(dismissModals:)
                                                 name:@"CloseAllModalViews"
                                               object:nil];
```

Put this in your doneBtn method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CloseAllModalViews" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Comment: thats awesome, this does work. only down side is i don't get a nice transition. if i animate the current modal, the middle modal will not dismiss (i'm guessing since the current modal is dismissing animatedly, that the second dismiss gets lost). i can not animate the current modal and animate the middle modal, but then i briefly see the second modal before the transition. i can not animate either, and goes straight to the base modal. i would prefer to have some animated transition, do you think thats possible? (i'll update post with working new code)

Comment: You may need to add some delays or timing if you want them to animate correctly. I'll admit it isn't the most elegant solution to the problem, but it does work. If you find a decent workaround, please post it.